# Importing Automapper into a angular2 webpack project

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to use the [ts automapper libary](https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) in an Angular2 webpack project but not sure how to import it or include it. An example how to accomplish this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There maybe be better way to work with this library, however, what I have done in my project is this

```
   /** test.component.ts
    ** Please note that you need to change Path as this is referenced to my node_module and probably it's different in your end. 
   **/

/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/automapper-ts/dist/automapper.d.ts" />  

import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  private jsonObj;
  constructor() {
    automapper.map("JSON", "newType", this.jsonObj);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Keep in mind I have amended `tsconfig.json` file to get that to work.

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

to

```
"moduleResolution": "classic",
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Are you using webpack? If you reference it like this, are you getting all the intellisense in automapper?

Comment: Yes I am using Webpack, as far as I work with yes it's working ok. give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have found a working solution. The exact same question you are asking, has been issued and answered at the library's GitHub page as well: https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper/issues/17.

In short:

- Install the automapper-ts library using npm: npm install automapper-ts --save
- Add the following line to the file typings.d.ts: declare module 'automapper-ts';
- Add the automapper-ts minified JS file to the scripts array in angular-cli.json: "../node_modules/automapper-ts/dist/automapper.min.js"
- Import the module created in step 2 in your module/component file: import { } from 'automapper-ts';

Now you should be able to use the `automapper` global variable as documented.

Comment: I'd like to add that, in your module/component `import 'automapper-ts/dist/automapper';`

Answer (score 1):

My two cents to this conversation:

In your tsconfig.json file make sure that you have the right path for your typings.d.ts file

> "typeRoots": [
>         "node_modules/@types",
>         "../src/typings.d.ts"
>       ],

Otherwise you might get some nasty "automapper is not defined" errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. install "automapper-ts" package with yarn or npm
2. import package:

   > import "automapper-ts";
3. use autommaper as it's described in documentation:

   > automapper.initialize(...) or automapper.createMap(...) etc.