# Why can't I import from AutoMapper (TS) and generate a Require statement

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I am using the [AutoMapper package](https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper) with TypeScript version 2.0.3 but when I try to import it, I always get the error "'automapper-ts' is not a module":

[image]

[image]

If I look in the definition file, it starts with:

```
declare module AutoMapperJs {
```

and it contains export statements.

If I change my import statement to this, it compiles:

```
import {} from 'automapper-ts/dist/automapper';
```

but then I don't get a Require statement and the global automapper static variable is not found at runtime. To get it to work, I have to replace the import statement with a reference:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/automapper-ts/dist/automapper.d.ts" />
```

and then add a manual JavaScript link:

```
<script src="lib/automapper-ts/dist/automapper.js"></script>
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `import "automapper-ts/dist/automapper";` which should import the package and let you use the automapping stuff such as `automapper.initialize(<...>);` and so on.

This is similar to the RxJS package which is also not modularized and global (as far as I remember).

**Thanks. Following the above suggestion and comments below, here is what I had to change to get everything working, although I still get the compiler error during build (see note below):**

Add this to the systemjs.config.js file:

```
    map: {
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'automapper-ts': 'npm:automapper-ts',
    },
    packages: {
        "automapper-ts": {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
    }
```

Then just use the import statement in my component.ts file:

```
import 'automapper-ts/dist/automapper';
```

This generated the correct Require statement.

Comment: That is interesting. That moves the TypeScript error out of WebStorm IDE (that is, it now builds) but the same 'xxx is not a module' is issued by the compiler. The site is deployed but the page fails with a 404 and the path is: http://localhost:8004/automapper-ts/dist/automapper (note no JS ext).

Comment: Depending on how you're doing the resolution of paths (like, say SystemJS) you might need an entry for it specifically.

Comment: This is in my systemJS file: 'automapper': 'npm:automapper-ts'

Comment: Probably you'll need a package entry, taking a guess here since I don't use SystemJS, but if you have a packages set up:

`packages = { <...>, "automapper-ts": { defaultExtension: "js" } }`

Comment: I have marked this question as answered because it did result in my code working and generating a Require statement as per the question. However, readers should be aware that it still issues a compiler error that 'automapper is not a module', so you may prefer to use a reference and a link statement instead.

Answer (score 3):

When I created the AutoMapperTS package, there was not much need for using a module system. Nowadays, using one is ;) . Therefore, when you like using AutoMapperTS (thanks for that!), you have to stick to importing it as a classic global library.

Coding-wise, it is not that hard to create a modular version of AutoMapperTS. The problem lies in supporting both worlds. I did try refactoring AutoMapperTS to a modular approach, which did work fine. I could however not get a working version for classic users. Given the pretty large user base, this is mandatory.

I am currently considering creating a second, modular, AutoMapperTS library. You will probably get notified if I manage to do so ;)...

Comment: Thanks, your "creation" saved me many of hours. I'd send you some bitcoin :)

Answer (score 1):

My two cents to this conversation (in case you are using Angular CLI):

In addition to following the instructions outlined here [Importing Automapper into a angular2 webpack project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692661/1698964), in your tsconfig.json file make sure that you have the right path for your typings.d.ts file

"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types", "../src/typings.d.ts" ],

Otherwise you might get some nasty "automapper is not defined" errors.